# How to merge/compare several tables by complex terms in R

Tags: r, merge, compare

I tried to compare two tables by two terms. My code in R:

```
cbr <- c("usd", "eur", "sek", "rur")
value <- c(2, 4, 5, 9)
data <- data.frame(cur = cbr, rate = value)

deals1 <- c("usd", "usd", "usd", "eur", "sek", "eur", "rur", "sek")
deals2 <- c("rur", "rur", "eur", "rur", "rur",  "usd", "usd", "rur")
day <- 1:8
dealsN <- data.frame(day = day, cur_1 = deals1, cur_2 = deals2)

for (i in 1:nrow(dealsN)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
        if (dealsN$cur_1[i] == data$cur[j] & dealsN$cur_2[i] == "rur") {
            dealsN$data[i] <- data$rate[data$cur[j]]
        } else if
           (dealsN$cur_1[i] == data$cur[j] & dealsN$cur_2[i] != "rur") {
             dealsN$data[i] <- data$rate[data$cur[dealsN$cur_2[i]]]   /data$rate[data$cur[j]] 
        }
    }
}

dealsN
```

But something is not well and the result is wrong:

```
 day cur_1 cur_2 data
    1   1   usd   rur 9.00
    2   2   usd   rur 9.00
    3   3   usd   eur 1.00
    4   4   eur   rur 2.00
    5   5   sek   rur 5.00
    6   6   eur   usd 2.50
    7   7   rur   usd 1.25
    8   8   sek   rur 5.00
```

It should be like this, as I hope:

```
day cur_1   cur_2   data
1   usd      rur    2
2   usd      rur    2
3   usd      eur    2
4   eur      rur    4
5   sek      rur    5
6   eur      usd    0,5
7   rur      usd    0,22
8   sek      rur    5
```

Help me please!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not mark! It is R!